# Python NOT reading Functions from another file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a main file called run.py and another file called CheckAcc.py

I want to link these two guys so variables would be passed over. But it doesn't work. I have the following code:

run.py

```
from getpass import getpass
from distutils.dir_util import copy_tree
from CheckAcc import *

id = 'C1'
username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass() 

checkAccF()
createAccF()
```

Here is the functions.py

```
import os
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import textfsm
import subprocess
import bs4

from run import username, password, id

#### FUNCTION 1 
def checkAccF():
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
        try:
        ....

#### FUNCTION 2 
def createAccF():
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as DEVNULL:
        try:
        ....
```

The error I get is:

```
NameError: name 'checkAccF' is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you importing *functions.py*?

Comment: Sorry I just fixed that.. The filename is CheckAcc.py - But the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

You need import the target functions' module explicitly:

```py
from functions import checkAccF, createAccF
```

Comment: Just tried that - gave another error::: ImportError: cannot import name 'checkAccF' from 'CheckAcc' (/var/py/CheckAcc.py)

Comment: Show your file structure, try `tree` or `find`.